# copytoClipboard in reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have 1 paragraph tag.My goal is to copy the content of

tag. Following code works fine for copying text from text area. I want to implement this to paragraph tag not to textarea tag .
I want to change the button's text to 'copied' once the content gets copied. Thanks in advance.

```
 <p id="content">Hi hello world</p>
 <textarea ref={(textarea) => this.textArea = textarea}/>
 <button onClick={() => this.copyCodeToClipboard()}> Copy </button>

   copyCodeToClipboard = () => {
     const el = this.textArea;
     el.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }
```

Comment: Why would you want the text in the paragraph tag to be copied? It cannot be edited by the user. Please specify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same concept, you just need to set a state for button text change:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.textRef = React.createRef()
    this.state = {
      isCopied: false
    }
  }

  copyCodeToClipboard = () => {
    // Clipboard API adds more flexibility
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.textRef.current.textContent)
    this.setState({
      isCopied: true
    })
    setTimeout(
      () =>
        this.setState({
          isCopied: false
        }),
      1000 // Time before button text change
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p ref={this.textRef}>Hi hello world</p>
        <button onClick={() => this.copyCodeToClipboard()}>
          {this.state.isCopied ? "Copied" : "Copy"}{" "}
        </button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <input placeholder="Paste here to test" />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can copy from a paragraph. What you can try though it

1. Create a textarea on the fly.
2. Assign the innertext of the parapgrap to it,
3. Add the text area to the document.body
4. Execute copy on it
5. And remove it immediately.

See example snippet below

```
    function copyText() {
      const textEl = document.createElement('textarea');
      const paragraph = document.getElementById('ptag');

      textEl.value = paragraph.innerHTML;

      document.body.appendChild(textEl);

      textEl.select();
      document.execCommand('copy');

      document.body.removeChild(textEl);
    }
```

You should know though that if the paragraph has child elements and you don't want to copy them, it's up to you to clean them up. A simple method like this can remove the tags.

```
htmlElement.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, ' ');
```

You should run it on innerText before assigning to textArea value.